# --name parameter for cucumber in Android

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I want my build.gradle to handle paramters for my cucumber tests.

It goes something like this :

```
switch (project.getProperties().get("testType")) {
            case "validate":
                arguments = [features: "features/remote",
                             glue: "com.myproject.feature.remote",
                             tags: "@newAndroid--~@skip--~@skipAndroid"]
                break;
            case "local":
            case "generic":
        }
```

This way, I can run my tests with command :

```
gradlew cAT -PtestType="validate"
```

Which gets my cucumber arguments already filled in, in my Runner class :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    this.cucumberInstrumentationCore.create(bundle);
    start();
}
```

This works great, but I'm facing a problem for the "name" parameter (to be able to run a specific scenario).

If I add the option in my runner this way :

```
bundle.putString("name", "^feature$");
```

It does work and run any scenario that has the string "feature" in it, exactly what i want.

However, in my build.gradle, if I simply add :

```
arguments = [features: "features/remote",
                                 glue: "com.myproject.feature.remote",
                                 name: '^feature$']
```

It does not work (when again, the other parameters such as feature and glues, do work)

For some reason, I'm not seeing logs in the Android Monitor, so what the cause of the problem is.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the regex ?

Any idea ?